# Making Google Places work with React localhost

Tags: reactjs, webpack, localhost, google-places

Google Places API script link is at the bottom of index.html. When I visit localhost:3000 the code works fine but when I go to localhost:3000/set-location, it stops working as if it's not there. I'm using Webpack and it's dev server

[webpack.js](https://gist.github.com/dantenovski/1051c43aaa39f215ceb383e1f4be9e95)

[App.js](https://gist.github.com/dantenovski/364d99019afb3b09292ca381a9697b92)

[Header.js](https://gist.github.com/dantenovski/6f796f81e380c36dbb61662808642b60)

[index.html](https://gist.github.com/dantenovski/b2811e2191e9420663e5de03b4ccb42f)

[index.js](https://gist.github.com/dantenovski/5efdab2da6ff9f1631a9303b5a843e37)

Comment: Have you inspected the sources to see if the script is present ? What error message are you getting ?

Comment: When I do view source it tells me Cannot GET /edit-profile. But bootstrap works on the page as expected. I assume Webpack compiles physical files but not remote scripts? Or it has something to do with React Router. I can view page source code of localhost in browser but not other urls like localhost:3000/register etc.

Comment: If the script link is in your index file it should be accessible all the time. It should have nothing to do with webpack or react router. Can you post the code from all the relevant files ? There is too little information to help you

Comment: @ThunderDev I've added the files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since Google Places API script doesn't depend on DOM, I placed it in the head. Then dynamically loaded autocomplete.js in componentDidMount():

```
 componentDidMount(){
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "./assets/js/autocomplete.js";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
```